# Scroll is not working in Appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

I used scrollToExact & scrollTo methods to scroll down page in appium & application is crashing many times.

driver.scrollToExact("India")

Comment: if your application is crashing, you are probably ending up finding a bug. If appium is crashing, please share the logs and some more details over the code.

Comment: Yeah, It's a critical bug. Your app is causing app crash , not appium :)

Answer (score 0):

Use This

driver.scrollTo("India");

Answer (score 0):

`scrollToExact` and `scrollTo` method is depricated since JAVA client version 4.0.0 (https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/README.md).

You can use `UiScrollable` and `UiSelector` and their methods to scroll any page (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html).

Example of code:

> @AndroidFindBy (uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(new
>   UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"Question
>   \"))")

If you want scroll to the bottom of page, please create method that will do several steps to find last element of page, otherwise you will get an error (Element not found)

Comment: I noticed this answer is similar to 3 others you posted in the past 30 minutes. If the questions are similar enough, vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates.